# How to enable download and upload in webwiev

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I tried to download and upload files in Android webview, but I can't do that. How do I enable upload and download files in webviewin Android  using Java?

Answer (score 0):

I can use this
System.enebledownload();
System.enebleupload();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).